# AddAzureAD does not exist in the current context (Asp.net core web app with Azure AD integration)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have been trying to follow tutorials showing how to hook .net core web apps up to Azure AD.

An example of one of these tutorials is here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp

In each example I find, the following code is included in startup.cs

```
        services.AddAuthentication(AddAzureAD.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

The AddAzureAD does not resolve however (does not exist in current context). A bit of googling says I should install:

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI -Version 2.2.0

However when I try to do this with my sample project (in .Net Core 2.1) I get an error saying I need to add package xxxxxx (e.g. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery) version 2.2.0 manually. I do this, and then it shows another package. And another, and another. Repeat ad infinitum.

Where am I going wrong, and why can't I get AddAzureAD to resolve or find a library to include to allow it to resolve? Can't get far without this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using .net core 2.1 project, you need to install package `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI -Version 2.1.1`.

For `AddAzureAD.AuthenticationScheme`, you could replace it with `AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`.